# Terraform looping when creating subscription filter in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to use Terraform to add a subscription filter to a Cloudwatch log group so
that my lambda is invoked whenever there is a new log event. When I use the AWS console to do it manually, I simply add the filter in Cloudwatch and a resource-based policy is automatically added to my lambda that looks like this

```
{
 "StringEquals": {
  "AWS:SourceAccount": "111"
 },
 "ArnLike": {
  "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:myRegion:111:log-group:/aws/apigateway/id/stage:*"
 }
}
```

And it works fine!

Now I want to do exactly the same thing but with terraform but it does not work.
I have the following resources defined:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "sub" {
  name            = "test"
  log_group_name  = "/aws/apigateway/id/stage"
  destination_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:myRegion:111:function:myFunction"
  filter_pattern  = ""
}
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "myFunction"
  principal     = "logs.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:apigateway:myRegion:111:log-group:/aws/apigateway/id/stage:*"
}
```

Now when I apply this code, the resource `aws_lambda_permission` is added but then terraform starts to loop creating the `aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter`. It loops for 5 minutes then it fails. When I look in the console, the lambda permission policy looks like this

```
{
 "ArnLike": {
  "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:apigateway:myRegion:111:log-group:/aws/apigateway/id/stage:*"
 }
}
```

1. What am I doing wrong here? Why is terraform looping?
2. Would it be possible to rewrite the permission to allow any/all log groups? Because I need to add 10 subscription filters would be good if I could avoid creating 10 permissions too.